# Split a string containing fixed length columns

Tags: string, parsing, powershell, split

I got data like this:

```
3LLO24MACT01 24MOB_6012010051700000020100510105010              123456
```

It contains different values for different columns when I import it.

Every column is fixed width:

- Col#1 is the ID and just 1 long. Meaning it is `"3"` here.
- Col#2 is 3 in length and here `"LLO"`.
- Col#3 is 9 in length and `"24MACT01 "` (notice that the missing ones gets filled up by blanks).
- This goes on for 15 columns or so...

Is there a  method to quickly cut it into different elements based on sequence length? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with RegEx matching, and creating an array of custom objects. Something like this:

```powershell
$AllRecords = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt | Where{$_ -match "^(.)(.{3})(.{9})"} | ForEach{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Col1' = $Matches[1]
        'Col2' = $Matches[2]
        'Col3' = $Matches[3]
    }
}
```

That will take each line, match by how many characters are specified, and then create an object based off those matches. It collects all objects in an array and could be exported to CSV or whatever. The 'Col1', 'Col2' etc are just generic column headers I suggested due to a lack of better information, and could be anything you wanted.

**Edit:** Thank you iCodez for showing me, perhaps inadvertantly, that you can specify a language for your code samples!

Answer (score 3):

[`[Regex]::Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do this rather easily.  All you need to do is specify a Regex pattern that has `.` followed by the number of characters you want in curly braces.  For example, to match a column of three characters, you would write `.{3}`.  You then do this for all 15 columns.

To demonstrate, I will use a string that contains the first three columns of your example data (since I know their sizes):

```powershell
PS > $data = '3LLO24MACT01 '
PS > $pattern = '(.{1})(.{3})(.{9})'
PS > ([Regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).Groups).Value
3LLO24MACT01 
3
LLO
24MACT01 
PS >
```

Note that the first value outputted will be the text matched be all of the capture groups.  If you do not need this, you can remove it with slicing:

```powershell
$columns = ([Regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).Groups).Value
$columns = $columns[1..$columns.Length]
```

Answer (score 2):

[New-PSObjectFromMatches](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87) is a helper function for creating PS Objects from regex matches.

The `-Debug` option can help with the process of writing the regex.