# How can I save lines with spaces between characters in the right way (Array)?

Tags: arrays, powershell, line, spaces

Two examples of Lines:

```
Bob                     02 02 10 80   Enquiries            
Martin      Corp        02 02 10 80   Langar
```

Note, that the first line doesn't have an information after "Bob", so just spaces.

So my code would be:

```
$account_name = $inputFileContent[$i].Split(" ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Edit:
My output-array should be like:

```
$account_name =
Bob
(Empty Line)
02
02
10
80
Enquiries
```

Is there a way to change the code, so I have it saved in a array in that format?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is a bit vague, what is the exact outcome you're hoping for?

Comment: from where do you get your information? Maybe you could import it in a different format

Comment: My output array should be like: 

$account_name =
Bob
(Empty line)
02
02
10
80
Enquiries

Comment: I'd use Excel Import with [Fixed width option](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/05/08/importing-fixed-width-text-files/) to import the data, then save it as csv. You can then use `Import-Csv`

Comment: Thanks Mathias for welcoming me! 
I have a txt file where I am getting the lines, the output file is also a txt file but in a sorted and formatted way. That's why I need help with the array. I'm not really working with Excel.

Comment: I edited my question, so my output should be clear now :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string containing fixed length columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932737/split-a-string-containing-fixed-length-columns)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use regular expressions:

```
Get-Content "data.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -match "^([a-z]+) +(\w*) +((?:\d{2} ){3}\d{2}) +(\w+)$" | Out-Null

    $account_name = 1..4 | ForEach-Object {$matches[$_]}
}
```

This will set `$account_name` to:

```
Bob

02 02 10 80
Enquiries
```

or:

```
Martin
Corp
02 02 10 80
Langar
```

Of course, `$account_name` is over-written each time, so either use it before looping around to the next line, or add each set of items to an array.

**Note:** I assumed you actually wanted the 'code' as a single item (e.g. '02 02 10 80'), but if not, the pattern can be adjusted to pull out the individual items.

Comment: `"^([a-z]+) +(\w*) +((?:\d{2} ){3}\d{2}) +(\w+)\s*$"` to handle  trailing spaces (or remove the `$` from regex).

Comment: @JosefZ Good call

Comment: Thank you! Looks like a very good solution :)
But I'm getting an error when trying to run the script:

#error
#Cannot index into a null array.
A#At C:\Users\...ps1
# +         $account_name = 1..4 | ForEach-Object {$matches[$_]}
# +                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
# + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
# + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: General question: How do i format some text in a coment here as a code? xD

Comment: Looks like you didn't get a match, but still tried to use `$matches`.  Likely because the target string is different to the examples you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Your input lines contain *fixed width* as opposite to *comma separate* values, so you can't use a delimiter (space) to parse the data which may contain empty values. Instead you have to use the position of the values in the string.

Here is an example line, which I have added index numbering above:

```
 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
  Martin      Corp        02 02 10 80   Langar
```

You can notice the first value `Martin` starts from the second character, index number `1` and is at most 12 characters long. Second value `Corp` starts from index `13` and is at most 11 characters long, after which first value `02` starts and so on.

We use `substring(1,12)` to get a 12 characters long slice from the line starting from index `1`. To remove (trailing) empty spaces from the string, we call `Trim()` method.

To create a new object containing data of each line, we use `[PSCustomObject]` and give names to object properties, or headers if you wish. `+=` operator adds that object to the array.

`test.txt`

```
 Bob                     02 02 10 80   Enquiries            
 Martin      Corp        02 02 10 80   Langar
```

Script:

```
$array = @() # Create an empty array

Get-Content .\test.txt | foreach{ # Read test.txt file and handle each line with foreach
    $array += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Field1 = $_.substring(1,12).Trim();
        Field2 = $_.substring(13,11).Trim();
        Field3 = $_.substring(25,2).Trim();
        Field4 = $_.substring(28,2).Trim();
        Field5 = $_.substring(31,2).Trim();
        Field6 = $_.substring(34,2).Trim();
        Field7 = $_.substring(39); # Substring from index 39 to the end of line
    }
}

$array
```

To output the values each on its own line, you could do it for example by this:

```
$array | foreach{
    $_.Field1
    $_.Field2
    $_.Field3
    $_.Field4
    $_.Field5
    $_.Field6
    $_.Field7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable/)

A while ago, I have created a [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable/) for reading fixed tables like yours:

```
$Text = '
 Bob                     02 02 10 80   Enquiries
 Martin      Corp        02 02 10 80   Langar'
```

### -Header

As your `$Text` example has no header you just need to provide it for each column, e.g.:

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Header Name,Company,A,B,C,D,Comment $Text | Format-Table

Name   Company A  B  C  D  Comment
----   ------- -  -  -  -  -------
Bob            02 02 10 80 Enquiries
Martin Corp    02 02 10 80 Langar
```

### `02 02 10 80`

You might also define the `-Header` nas a single string which is than used to not just the column names but also the alignment of the columns. In your example, if `02 02 10 80` is actually a single column, you can just add a single column header for this column:

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Text -Header ' Name        Company     Code          Comment' | Format-Table

Name   Company Code        Comment
----   ------- ----        -------
Bob            02 02 10 80 Enquiries
Martin Corp    02 02 10 80 Langar
```

As long as you keep the surrounding columns `Company` and `Comment` (including the header) also left aligned. If that is not the case (and in some seldom other situations), you might also add a `-Ruler` parameter (see `Help ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Full`) to further define the alignment of your table.

### Specific to your answer:

As you can see from the example, the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet returns a list of objects (common to most other cmdlets) which you can easialy pipe to native cmdlets like [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6). In you specific case you might do something like this:

```
$Accounts = ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Text -Header `
' Name        Company     Code          Comment'

(($Accounts | Where-Object Name -eq 'Bob').PSObject.Properties).Value
```

Resulting in:

```
Bob

02 02 10 80
Enquiries
```