# Powershell extract data from text file and convert to csv

Tags: regex, string, powershell, substring

So I have a text file as shown below.

How could I use PowerShell to just grab the mac address and port number(far right column) and output it to a csv file with headers(mac, port)?

```
1        010D.0C93.A02C        Dynamic     Gi1/0/5
1        011B.782D.6719        Dynamic     Gi1/0/22
1        0003.4790.B479        Dynamic     Gi1/0/1
1        0054.B671.1EB8        Dynamic     Gi1/0/2
```

I have tried just looping through the text file and using -replace several times. I am left with the data I want, which is nice. But it seems overly complicated and I am still faced with the problem of outputting to csv with headers.

```
$file = Get-Content file.txt
$file | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ' ', '' -replace 'Dynamic', '' 
   -replace 'Management', '' -replace 'Gi1/0/', ', '}
```

This is what I have tried. And it outputs as such:

```
010D.0C93.A02C, 5
011B.782D.6719, 22
0003.4790.B479, 1
0054.B671.1EB8, 2
```

From here, I'm not sure how to turn this into a csv with headers( mac, port)
And like I said. There has got to be a more efficient way to filter out this data.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to filter out the parts you want (mac and port) like below:

```
$result = Get-Content -Path 'X:\file.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^.+?(?<mac>[0-9A-F]{4}\.[0-9A-F]{4}\.[0-9A-F]{4}).+?(?<port>\d+)$') {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'mac'  = $matches['mac']
            'port' = $matches['port']
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\macports.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

> ```
> mac            port
> ---            ----
> 010D.0C93.A02C 5   
> 011B.782D.6719 22  
> 0003.4790.B479 1   
> 0054.B671.1EB8 2
> ```

Regex details:

```
^                Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
.                Match any single character that is not a line break character
   +?            Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
(?<mac>          Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “mac”
   [0-9A-F]      Match a single character present in the list below
                 A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                 A character in the range between “A” and “F”
      {4}        Exactly 4 times
   \.            Match the character “.” literally
   [0-9A-F]      Match a single character present in the list below
                 A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                 A character in the range between “A” and “F”
      {4}        Exactly 4 times
   \.            Match the character “.” literally
   [0-9A-F]      Match a single character present in the list below
                 A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                 A character in the range between “A” and “F”
      {4}        Exactly 4 times
)
.                Match any single character that is not a line break character
   +?            Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
(?<port>         Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “port”
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
$                Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having said in the comments that Stack Overflow isn’t a code-writing service, I’m going to write some code anyway...

The code below assumes that the name of the file that stores your text is in the variable `$textfilename`, and that the name of the desired CSV file is in the variable `$csvfilename`.

```
Get-Content -Path $textfilename | 
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
            MAC=$_[9..22] -join ""
            Port=$_[44..($_.length-1)] -join ""
        }
    } | 
        Export-CSV -Path $csvfilename -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that I figured out the "field positions" for the substringing by sitting there and counting; there are undoubtedly better ways to do it. My code gives the port name rather than just the number (that is, I produce "Gi1/0/22" instead of just "22"). The key, though, is that you want to create a `PSObject` with member properties `MAC` and `Port`, assign the requisite values to those properties, and then send those objects to the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a general solution (where the columns are automatically defined), you might want to try this [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable/), see also: [How can I save lines with spaces between characters in the right way (Array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143299/1701026).
I have just added a new feature where you can supply a list of column (property) names rather then an aligned header line:

```
$Table = '
1        010D.0C93.A02C        Dynamic     Gi1/0/5
1        011B.782D.6719        Dynamic     Gi1/0/22
1        0003.4790.B479        Dynamic     Gi1/0/1
1        0054.B671.1EB8        Dynamic     Gi1/0/2'

ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Header Count,Address,Mode,Port $Table |
    Select-Object -Property Address, @{n = 'Port'; e = {$_.Port.Split('/')[-1]}}

Address        Port
-------        ----
010D.0C93.A02C 5
011B.782D.6719 22
0003.4790.B479 1
0054.B671.1EB8 2
```